# How do I get max() from a list of dates?

Tags: python, datetime, max, arcpy

Using Python 3.6.8

I had the below portion of my script working previously on some test data, but now that I've tried to spool it up to the production data, it's not working. This is a snippet of a much larger script, but I believe my error is somewhere in these lines of code below. The field that the SearchCursor is searching is a date type field and every record has a date in it (no nulls/none).

It is looking at a list of dates and should be assessing the 'max' (most recent) but on line 25 it's returning:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and
>   'datetime.datetime'

Here is my pared-down code:

```
import arcpy
import datetime
from datetime import time, timedelta

# Environment
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace =r"C:\GIS\CAD_reporting\CAD_reporting.gdb"
arcpy.env.scratch = r"C:\GIS\CAD_reporting\CAD_reporting.gdb"

workspace = r"C:\GIS\CAD_reporting\CAD_reporting.gdb"
ptFC = r"C:\GIS\CAD_reporting\CAD_reporting.gdb\RMI_pts"
dateList=[]
nowDT = (datetime.datetime.today()).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
lowDate = datetime.datetime.today()

# START
print ("Start: " + nowDT)

# Get date for the query start(low date)
dtCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ptFC, "ReportQueryDate")
for row in dtCursor:
    dateList.append(row)
del dtCursor

maxDateTuple = max(dateList) # TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'

lowDate = maxDateTuple[0] - timedelta(days=200) # subtracts 200 days
lowDateString = lowDate.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
print (lowDateString)
```

I can tell this error has to do with the data types, but I'm not sure how to handle my variables, to get them into the same/correct format for comparison.

Comment: At some point in your for-loop, you are inserting `None` into `dateList` without meaning to. I would add an if-statement in the loop, and only append to `dateList` if row is not `None`.

Comment: An option is to filter out none type as you take max, i.e. maxDataTuple = max([vdate for vdate in dateList if vdate is not None])

Answer (score -1):

Moderators: perhaps delete this question?

I discovered that I was wrong about all records in the SearchCursor field having a date value: there was a definition query applied within ArcGIS that was filtering what I saw to only those that had dates.

They python syntax posted above was correct and does work, assuming all records in the table have a valid date value.

Comments posted above that suggest 'handling' the Nones would also work to resolve the issue.